# Force side of street on HERE Maps API route waypoints

Tags: here-api

When generating a route using the HERE API, I would like to force the route to travel down a certain side of the street. For example, there may be a pickup point on the westbound side of the 2-way street. A U-turn is not possible, thus, I need to ensure the route travels westbound through the waypoint and not eastbound. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the Waypoint Parameter "passThrough":

http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html

Comment: Thanks, but no, I already use passThrough waypoints. The problem is a bit different. Imagine 3 waypoints (A, B, C) on a single north-south street. A and C are on the east (northbound) side of the street, but B is on the west (southbound) side of the street. As long as the route goes past B, it doesn't care that which side of the street B was on. In reality, if I wanted to stop at B, I would probably have to turn left a block ahead, and then make 3 right turns to circle back this stop.

Comment: To add some context, this is for routing a school bus. I can only use a set of designated stops, and can't have kids running across the street in traffic to the other side of the street.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your answer. I'm not sure if this is what you meant or not, but here is how I solved this:

Comment: First, find 2 reference waypoints for each bus stop as the "approaching waypoint" and the "departing waypoint". This can be semi-automated by adding to the coordinates (e.g. add 0.0001 to latitude for the departing waypoint of a Northbound stop to get a point ~15 metres north of it). Then, for each A-B route, request A-departingA-arrivingB-B with the middle two as passThroughs